# Nexus 3 docker proxy to a v1 proxy not working (using v2 api calls)

Tags: docker, proxy, nexus3

I have a Nexus 3 docker proxy repository created proxying an old v1 repository we have.  No matter what I do, the nexus proxy is attempting to make /v2 api calls to the proxy.  I have v1 support on the nexus 3 proxy enabled.

The following is logged:

> 2017-07-27 19:52:47,956+0000 WARN  [qtp1927946838-333] awang org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.DockerProxyFacetImpl - Could not parse error response Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4462b3e0; line: 1, column: 2]
>   2017-07-27 19:52:47,957+0000 WARN  [qtp1927946838-333]  org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Is the remote url a valid docker endpoint? Remote host https:/// with path /v2//manifests/ did not return the expected response. Error message: unknown

Looking at the logs on the docker registry server I only see v2 requests.

Is this supposed to work or is this not supported?

Also, I was trying to self-troubleshoot this and I don't see the docker repository code in the nexus-public repository.  Is the source code for this stuff not available?

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?